# La forme particulière que la protéine doit prendre et que l'on nomme aussi « fold » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, terminologie, science

> However, only knowing this sequence tells us little about what the
> protein does and how it does it. In order to carry out their function
> (e.g. as enzymes or antibodies), they must take on a particular shape,
> also known as a “**fold**.”
>
> Cependant, le fait de simplement connaître cette séquence nous en dit peu sur ce
> que la protéine fait et comment elle le fait. Afin de pouvoir
> fonctionner (comme enzyme ou anticorps), elle doit prendre une
> forme particulière, qu'on nomme aussi ...
>
> [*Folding@home* : Diseases. Je souligne ; ma traduction sommaire.](https://foldingathome.org/diseases/)

J'ai compris que *folding* dans ce context c'est le [*repliement*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8381896) [*des protéines*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repliement_des_prot%C3%A9ines) (« Étape de la transformation structurale d'une protéine, au cours de laquelle les acides aminés qui la constituent interagissent entre eux pour lui donner une conformation spatiale caractéristique. » définition au GDT), et que le [*misfolding*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8381895) c'est le *mauvais repliement*. J'essaye de comprendre à quoi correspond le terme [*fold*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fold#Noun) entre guillemets dans ce contexte : est-ce *pli/repli/repliement/replissage* ou autrement (*structure* ?) ?

Answer (score 1):

**pliage des protéines**

Libellé préféré : pliage des protéines;

Synonyme MeSH : pliage protéique;

Synonyme CISMeF : repliement des protéines globulaires;

Hyponyme MeSH : Pliage des protéines globulaires;

[CHU-Rouen](http://www.chu-rouen.fr/page/mesh-descripteur/pliage-des-proteines)

= as in, to fold the clothes
= plier les vêtements

Même idée

Answer (score 0):

Si le mot doit représenter la forme, c'est **pliure** qui paraît le plus adapté :

...une forme particulière, aussi appelée **pliure**.

On pourrait aussi éventuellement l'appeler **repliement**.

S'il s'agit de l'action de plier, pas son résultat, on peut envisager *pliage* mais ce n'est pas ce que semble indiquer le texte anglais. Ç’aurait été correct s'il était écrit *also known as a "folding"*.